# Add a font to mPDF v8.0.6

Tags: php, mpdf

I downloaded the font `Dancing Script` from Google and want to use it in a PDF generated by mPDF v8.0.6.  I followed their instructions, here is my code:

```
$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs      = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData          = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
  'fontDir'  => array_merge($fontDirs, [
    __DIR__ . '/custom-fonts',
  ]),
  'fontdata' => $fontData + [
    'DancingScript' => [
      'R' => 'DancingScript.ttf',
      'I' => 'DancingScript.ttf',
      'B' => 'DancingScript.ttf',
    ],
  ],
  // 'default_font' => 'DancingScript',
]);

// $mpdf->AddFontDirectory(__DIR__ . '/custom-fonts');  //with or without this line doesnt matter
$mpdf->WriteHTML($this->htmlContent);
$mpdf->Output($this->filename, 'F');
```

In my HTML I set the font-family, but the font is not used:

```
footer {
  font-family: DancingScript;
}
```

I also tried in quotes, but no luck.

Comment: Have you try to apply direct to `div/p/a` you want that style? for example: `<div style="font-family: DancingScript;"></<div>`

Comment: Exactly how are you using the CSS class `footer` in your HTML?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I tried right now and it still did not work, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Dave it is not a class, it is the `footer` element. I tested the CSS selector by changing the font colour to red, and it does change to red, so the CSS selector is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font name has to be lowercase. See point 2. in fonts example in documentation https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html